# Unable to display images in wwwroot/images on my webpage

Tags: .net, razor

// The cshtml file is located in /Views/Home/Index.cshtml

// Content in the cshtml file

```
<a href="http://google.com>
<img src="/wwwroot/images/image.png">
</a>
```

I tried accessing the image in both /Content/Images/image.png and /wwwroot/images/image.png and getting a 404 error. Onclicking the link in the image tag takes me to the correct location.

I have also added the following code in Startup.cs:

```
app.UseStaticFiles();
```

The problem exists even for JS files in /wwwroot/lib folder.

> > GET https://localhost:6001/wwwroot/lib/sample.js
> >     info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[2]
> >           Request finished in 2.4702ms 404

Comment: Remove the `/wwwroot` part. `<img src='~/images/image.png'>`

Comment: That doesn't seem to work. I have updated my question with the location of the cshtml file

Comment: It does not matter where the location of your chtml file. You are prefixing it with `~`  . Make sure you are using single or double quotes for your attribute values.(your question did not have those). This (`<img src='~/images/image.png'>`) should work as long as you have that image present in the directory

Comment: Sorry, the attribute value does have quotes and the path "~/images/image.png" does not seem to work either.

Comment: Are you sure you have that image present in that directory ? What version of MVC are you in ? dot net core 2 ? MVC 5  ?

Comment: dot net core 2, image is present for sure, clicking the link in the attribute takes me to the image

Comment: This is not just for images I am unable to even access javascript files in /wwwroot/lib folder. On clicking the link from within the cshtml file takes me to the file but it shows a 404 Error on the logs when I try to access the the URL from the browser

Comment: Can you please add  app.UseStaticFiles(); just before   app.UseMvc(); I have also faced this issue earlier. but now fixed

Answer (score 0):

remove the ~/
src='images/image.png'>

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).